# Mean of wc -l in grep command

Tags: ubuntu-mate, grep, binary

Is the wc -l showing how many times the search string is found in the binary file?

-l, --lines
print the newline counts (I think a newline is an empty line?)

```
 grep --binary-files=text 'postal_code77586' formhistory.sqlite | wc -l

andy@7 ~/Downloads> grep --binary-files=text 'postal_code77586' formhistory.sqlite | wc -l
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. -l counts lines (in this case from the output of grep command), -w counts words (strings) and -b counts characters (bytes).

I personally would use the grep parameter -c to get the same result. In this example:

```
grep -c --binary-files=text 'postal_code77586' formhistory.sqlite
```

No pipe to wc needed.

Answer (score 1):

The program `wc`:

```
wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file
```

is very useful. In your example it is printing how many lines have the text `postal_code77586`, via the `-l` options. You had one line with that text.

The grep / wc pair of commands used this way is better suited to text files. If your file is truly binary, then the newline character will be merely be as hit is the binary stream and wouldn't really mean "lines" at all.

Note that regardless, if there are multiple occurrences of `postal_code77586` between newline characters, the count would still be 1.

Comment: Geany would not open the file, so I am sure it is a binary file. I used Ghex. @Doug Smythies